# Dynamically changing Circle Radius on Google map using zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using the Google maps javascript API V3. 
How do you dynamically resize a circle on a google map using the zoom level?  I use circles to represent gages, some of which are close to each other and overlap at low zoom levels
See .
I want to dynamically change radius as I change zoom levels.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When circles overlap, this is  [not forced by a specific zoom-level](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/yJTxZ/)

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the `zoom_changed` event

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

and then in the event handler can call `setRadius` on the circle

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle

Comment: Hi @barryhunter , I was able to trigger the zoom_changed event that youve suggested here. I have a follow up question made by user2933768 , how should we get the radius of the circle after the user change the zoom level? We know we can use the getRadius() method but the problem here is that the radius of the circle is dynamically changing as the zoom level change ? Your idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The idea is you know what the radius "should" be and want to change it. You have to store the nominal radius somewhere else and work from that. Getting it from 'getRadius' is the last computed one, which is pretty meaningless for the curretn zoom